# How to solve a distance problem inside of a picture?

Tags: matrices, approximation, 3d, coordinate-systems, computer-vision

sorry for my bad english. I have the following problem:

[image: illustration of problem]

In the picture you can see 4 different positions. Every position is known to me (longitude, latitude with screen-x and screen-y).

Now i want to know, where in the picture a specific position is. For example, i want to have a rectangle 20 meters in front and 5 meters to the left of me.

I also got the height of the camera, the rotation around X axis from the camera, the position of the camera (longitude,latitude) and the horizontal and vertical view angle of the camera.

Can i use simple mathematic operations to solve this problem?